# GA4 - Email open event showing in real-time, but not in reports?

Tags: events, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

In GA4, I cannot find a way for the real-time email open event to show in reports.

Here's the code that is in email signature:

> ```
> <img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&amp;tid=G-CODE###&amp;cid=555&amp;t=event&amp;en=email_open" /></p>
> ```

I can see it in real-time (without city) but it never shows in reports.

[real-time event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8904t.png)

[not showing in reports over 48 hours later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXEe6.png)

I've read about adding custom dimensions to the event to make it show in reports, I cant figure out how to do this.

Also, I've seen mention in another question here of making the pixel do a server-server post. I'm not sure how to do this either.

Any help appreciated, thanks

I'm aware that it takes up to 48 hours to register, it has been over a week. I've read through every blog post and checklist of possible issues. There are a handgul of other people out there asking the same question, none seem to have found an answer. Is this tracking not possible?

I've tried adding custom dimensions, but they are not triggering. I tried to use GOOGLE TAG MANAGER as well, but can't get those to trigger

Comment: It can happen due to low occurrence, causing longer wait times. To avoid hassle, utilize BigQuery to analyze streamed data.

Comment: thanks Ali, but that's not it. I suspect GA4 has done away with this possibility. I've seen someone on here who made the image load then post a server to server to trigger something on their page with GA4 installed. I don't know how to do this. I suppose some sort of script. But I don't know how to insert a script into my webmail signature